# Formula not working in VBA, but works in cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am doing a conditional statement and I have automated my spreadsheet using VBA. Everything works fine until it comes to this one formula. I am guessing it has to do with the text strings. I have tried using & Chr(34) & before and after and it's not working either.

Here's the formula:
`=IF(E2="RIA Review",IF(G2<=4,"Green",IF(G2=5,"Yellow","Red")), IF(E2="Delivery",IF(I2<=-7,"Green",IF(I2=-1,"Yellow","Red")),IF(E2="Launch/Close",IF(I2>=121,"Red",IF(I2>=111,"Yellow",IF(I2> =100,"Green","N/A"))),IF(OR(E2="Intent",E2="AE Review",E2="Initial Review",E2="AE Disposition"),IF(G2<=8,"Green",IF(OR(G2=9,G2=10)," Yellow",IF(G2>=11,"Red")))))))`

Here's the code in VBA (it changes the cell references, which I still have a hard time knowing if it's talking about the right cell)

```
Range("H2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IF(RC[-3]=""RIA Review"",IF(RC[-1]<=4,""Green"",IF(RC[-1]=5,""Yellow"",""Red"")),IF(RC[-3]=""Delivery"",IF(RC[1]<=-7,""Green"",IF(RC[1]=-1,""Yellow"",""Red"")),IF(RC[-3]=""Launch/Close"",IF(RC[1]>=121,""Red"",IF(RC[1]>=111,""Yellow"",IF(RC[1]>=100,""Green"",""N/A""))),IF(OR(RC[-3]=""Intent"",RC[-3]=""AE Review"",RC[-3]=""Initial Review"",RC[-3]=""AE Disposition"")," & _
"]<=8,""Green"",IF(OR(RC[-1]=9,RC[-1]=10),""Yellow"",IF(RC[-1]>=11,""Red"")))))))"
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: 1) something wrong here: `"]<=8,""Green""` 2) `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1` accept formulas with length less than 255 characters long

Comment: ughghghghg i hate these nested formulae. Rather than building a macro to do such an ugly formula operation, why not build a macro that will perform the desired validation, instead?  Real-time updates could be handled by the `Change` event of the worksheet...

Comment: Instead of being rude David Zemens - why not be helpful?  Did you ever consider that I am a beginner and have no idea what you are talking about?  It was hard enough to get the ugly nested formula to work.  But I was proud that I figured that out.  I have only been using excel and VBA for about 3 months, with no prior coding experience.  Next time offer real help rather than just being mean to someone looking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can understand in your formula in decision making, the **color** will depends on 3 columns: **E**, **G** and **I**.

With minimal coding, you can create a user defined function with that 3 range inputs so any of them changed will get color updated automatically.

Put in formula in a cell for color like `=ColorStatus(E2,G2,I2)` and below code in a Module. I also throw in case for column E that is not in any of your checks, plus the conditions are slightly different but same result (assuming no decimals in values).

**Updated color decision for "Delivery" from comments.**

```
Function ColorStatus(E As Range, G As Range, I As Range) As String
    Dim sColor As String

    Select Case E.Value
        Case "RIA Review"
            ' Color determined by column G
            Select Case G.Value
                Case Is < 5:    sColor = "Green"
                Case 5:         sColor = "Yellow"
                Case Else:      sColor = "Red"
            End Select
        Case "Delivery"
            ' Color determined by column I
            Select Case I.Value
                Case Is < -6:   sColor = "Green"
                Case -1 To -6:  sColor = "Yellow"
                Case 0 To 99:   sColor = "Red"
                Case Else:      sColor = "Black" ' From 100 days
            End Select
        Case "Launch/Close"
            ' Color determined by column I
            Select Case I.Value
                Case Is > 120:  sColor = "Red"
                Case Is > 110:  sColor = "Yellow"
                Case Is > 99:   sColor = "Green"
                Case Else:      sColor = "N/A"
            End Select
        Case "Intent", "AE Review", "Initial Review", "AE Disposition"
            ' Color determined by column G
            Select Case G.Value
                Case Is < 9:    sColor = "Green"
                Case 9, 10:     sColor = "Yellow"
                Case Else:      sColor = "Red"
            End Select
        Case Else
            sColor = "Unknown State" ' Or change to "" to appear blank
    End Select
    ColorStatus = sColor
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick!  I will test this out today and see if I can get it to work. Delivery is tricky.  If it's greater than 7 days prior to the date in column I then it's Green.  1-6 days prior to the date is Yellow.  If it's past the date, then it's Red.  And there is one condition that is not stated, which is if it's 100 days past the date then it's Black.

Comment: @user3605729 Welcome, you may want to share those column headers as we have no idea what are they for and type of data stored. I am assuming only whole numbers if not text. For **Delivery**, just add more cases, from 1 direction (smallest or largest).

Comment: Column E is used for Process Phase.  Column G is a whole number using the formula of networkdays-today grabbing a date from a different column to calucate the days it's been in that process phase.  Column I is also a whole numner calucated the same way as G, but using a different date to determine when something was suppose to Launch and if it has or not.

Comment: Updated code to match your **Delivery** conditions.

Comment: Thanks @user3605729. Hope you have learn some VBA and enjoyed it. Please mark as Answer to close this Question.